# Show that $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$ converges to 0

Tags: analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, radicals, epsilon-delta

I want to use the definition of the limit to show that $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$ converges to 0.

The definition is as follows: if $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$ converges to 0, then $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists an $N>0$ such that $n\ge N \implies \mid\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\mid<\epsilon$.

Now I want to start backwords in order to figure out how to pick N. I know:

$\mid\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\mid=\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$

since $n$ is a natural number and $\sqrt{n^2+1}>n$. So I need to pick an N such that $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n<\epsilon$. I tried multiplying $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$ by $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}$ but that didn't really seem to help.

Do you have any ideas on how to find this N?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: divide the expression by $n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$$
\verts{\root{n^{2} +1} - n - 0} = {1 \over \root{n^{2} +1} + n} < {1 \over 2n}
$$
Given $\epsilon > 0$
$$
n > N \equiv \floor{1 \over 2\epsilon} + 1
\quad\imp\quad
\verts{\root{n^{2} +1} - n} < \epsilon
\quad\imp\quad
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{\root{n^{2} +1} - n} = 0
$$

Answer (score 13):

Hint:

$$\sqrt{n^2+1}-n=\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}=\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\ldots$$

Comment: wow you skipped quite a few steps, and you have a weird notation for limes (is it really used?). Other then that, good hint

Comment: It is used a lot, and the "quite a few steps", if at all, is all very basic high school algebra.

Comment: I don't know how I ended up here, but the "wierd notation for limits" definitely made my day! +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 6):

If we do not wish to rationalize the numerator, note that for positive $n$ we have $\sqrt{n^2+1}\lt n+\frac{1}{2n}$, since $\left(n+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2=n^2+1+\frac{1}{4n^2}\gt n^2+1$.

Thus $\left|\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right|\lt \frac{1}{2n}$, and now $\epsilon$-$N$ works nicely.

Answer (score 5):

Note $$ - \frac{1}{n} \leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1 } + n} \leq \frac{1}{n} $$

we know $\frac{1}{n} \to 0 $. Apply squeeze rule now.

Comment: Yes, we definitely are the don(e)s. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio: Yours differ just in some alphabet `... ..selm.` and `... ..toni.` :D