# Prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sqrt{n^2+1} - n) = 0$ by definition of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, radicals, epsilon-delta

I know by definition that a sequence converges if $\exists p \in X$ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n>N$, $d(p_n, p) < \epsilon$. So I should find a $\epsilon$ that proves $| n (\sqrt{n^2+1} - n)-0| < \epsilon $.

Would it be correct to say that $\forall n>N$ such that $\sqrt{n^2+1} - n)$ < $\sqrt{N^2+1} - N) < \frac{1}{N} = \epsilon$? So in the end $N = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and this concludes that it does indeed converge to 0?

Comment: By "definition of convergence" seems to involve you knowing "somehow", or perhaps **guessing**, what the limit $\;p\;$ is. As an algebraic exercise it is fine, as a method it is, imo, very poor. And nop: you shouldn't find an $\;\epsilon>0\;$ that proves...etc. What you have to prove is that **for any given** $\;\epsilon >0\;$,  *there exists*  that $\;N\in\Bbb R\;$ such that....etc. These are proofs of *existence* .

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the reply! If it's any help, I'm using baby Rudin as a reference and I'm trying to 'mimic' what he's done for other proofs. Perhaps my understanding of his methods is very flawed, and so I may be misrepresenting it here.

Comment: This is a [rather similar questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546543/show-that-sqrtn21-n-converges-to-0). And perhaps also [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953214/proving-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sqrtn2-1-n-0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\epsilon > 0$, we want to find $N$ such that

$$ \sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n < \epsilon$$
for all $n \geq N$. Note that 
$$ \sqrt{n^2 + 1} -n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1} + n} < \frac1n.$$
Thus $$\sqrt{n^2 + 1} -n < \epsilon \quad \text{  for  }  \quad n\geq N = \frac1\epsilon.$$